# Combining two HTML files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two separate HTML files both with different css and javascript. The one file is a responsive burger menu and the other a desktop and laptop dropdown menu. I want to know if there is a way of making it so that when the device with is less than 700px it switches from the full navigation bar to the burger menu. Would I have to put both menus into one file?

Answer (score 1):

To switch from full *navbar* to burger menu, checkout the CSS `@media` rule.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    /* 
      Your code here (e.g burger menu class set to active)..
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You don't have to put both menus into one file.

You have several options:

1. **[Preferred option]** You structurally markup the menu once. You then use `@media` queries in your CSS, to determine the presentation of the menu when device width `> 700px` and when device width `< 700px`.
2. You can use a technique called RESS (Responsive Design + Server-Side Components) to load either one menu or the other. You could do this relatively simply using a short piece of if-else logic and 2 PHP server side includes.